# Unable to upload video files in drupal 7 with the video module

Tags: files, media

I am trying to make a simple video uploading site with Drupal. I am using the Video module. Let me tell you what I have done:

1) Just made a fresh installation of Drupal 7.7

2) Installed the [Video module](http://drupal.org/project/video)

3) Enabled the following

- Video
- Video UI

Now when I go to configuration tab I see the following error:

> Exception: You must have the cURL extension enabled to use this
>   library. in require_once()  (line 22 of
>   C:\wamp\www\freshdrupal\sites\all\modules\video\libraries\zencoder-php\Zencoder.php).

However I can still create a new content type and add field of video type. In that case when I add a content and upload video it gaves the same exception error as shown above.

Please help. If there is any substitute module for doing the same please tell me so. I need it urgently.

Comment: Still problem the error is now when i i click the config> transcoder tab  i see- Fatal error: Interface 'transcoder_interface' not found in C:\wamp\www\freshseven\sites\all\modules\media_zencoder\transcoders\media_zencoder.inc on line 1

Comment: I am having same problem. Exception: You must have the cURL extension enabled to use this library. in require_once() (line 22 of E:\xampp\htdocs\chimcat\sites\all\modules\video\libraries\zencoder-php\Zencoder.php). I am using xampp.
Help me please,
thank you very much,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your error, you need to have CURL installed.

If you're running a mac:
http://www.davidonzo.com/lng/en/post/986/php-mac-os-x-how-to-install-the-curl-library/

If you're running linux:
type in the command line - "apt-get install curl"

If you're running WAMP on Windows:
click the WAMP icon in task tray, then go to PHP > PHP Extensions > php_curl. Then restart apache.

Comment: thank you, i am running windows. the WAMP stack. and yes i know i have curl missing but apparently http://drupal.org/project/curl
has only support for drupal 6

Comment: Updated my answer, give that a try, snagged from here: http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=180453.0

Comment: just done that, now the previous error is gone. But when i click configure > transcoder i see another error 
( ! ) Fatal error: Interface 'transcoder_interface' not found in C:\wamp\www\freshseven\sites\all\modules\media_zencoder\transcoders\media_zencoder.inc on line 14

Comment: Whn i upload a video through a custom created content type it says 
This video is currently being processed. Please wait.

Comment: Ok, so we've solved the error mentioned in the original post.  Now you're going to have to set up FFMPEG like uwe999 suggested.  Perhaps make a new post somewhere else on stack exchange? just because the original question was solved and this is kindof no longer a "drupal" problem but a "local windows environment zen configuration" problem.

Comment: Here's a stack overflow post about installing ffmpeg on a wamp server. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172916/how-to-install-ffmpeg-in-wampserver-2-0-windows-xp

Comment: OK , since you say it is no longer a drupal problem i take it as a solution. But please help me along to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 0):

for the video module you have to configure an encoder, either FFMPEG (for video encoding on your server) or Zencoder (video encoding service).

Make sure to follow all the steps to configure Zencoder correctly including postback (I believe the postback is by ftp).

Comment: how do i configure zencoder

Comment: there is a documentation link on the project page: http://video.heidisoft.com/documentation/welcome-video-module-documentation

Comment: this tutorial works perfectly with drupal 6. Not with drupal 7. FileField required module is not still up for drupal 7. CCK is only on dev release. Can you please tell me how i can solve the issue?

Comment: still having same problem. Installed all the substitute modules in drupal 7 but when i click configure the error comes-Exception: You must have the cURL extension enabled to use this library. in require_once() (line 22 of C:\wamp\www\freshseven\sites\all\modules\video\libraries\zencoder-php\Zencoder.php).

Comment: i think i found the exact position of error. It comes whenever i try to access the transcoder configuration tab. All other are working good